# Can you use waterproof membrane to make the thinset adhere to the shower base

Tags: waterproofing, cement-board

Most the procedures I have seen show how that you tape the join between cement board and the shower base and then you apply thinset over that to the point that the thinset is flush with the cement board
I just came across a video showing another way to do it (and it makes sense to do it this way, in my opinion) and that way is to use tape and waterproof membrane first ..this will adhere to the acrylic shower base and it will allow the thinset to adhere easier in that area

See this video
https://youtu.be/icyor45wyCs?t=67
Is this OK ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not allowed
The guy in the video is doing something wrong, the redguard instructions do not say it will bond to acrylic

Instead use Kerdi band or similar and the recomended adhesive (Kerdi Fix or a replacement) like in [this video](https://youtu.be/48pwER0GFSs?t=1112)